# Como recuperar o click em uma matriz de botões

Tags: c#, array, winforms

Estou fazendo um campo minado, logo tenho que adicionar uma matriz de botões em um painel(para serem as casas). Criei a matriz de botões e adicionei cada botão[x][y] em um painel. Porém não sei como faço para recuperar o click em um determinado botão[x][y] dentro da minha matriz. Sei apenas gerar o evento para um botão, não sei como posso "generalizar" para os demais, para que, por exemplo, quando o botão[2][3], dentro da minha matriz for clickado eu receba um "botao[2][3] foi clickado" ou "as posições clickadas foram x = 2, y =3".
Sei que parece uma pergunta óbvia, mas é que iniciei hoje em C#.
Obrigado.

Comment: Tem mais de uma maneira de resolver esse problema. Acho que fica mais fácil responder a sua pergunta se você desse um exemplo do código que você tentou usar (apode fazer algo simplificado que só imprime uma mensagem na tela mesmo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um único evento gerado para todos os botões e dentro desse evento você verifica quem o disparou, algo desse jeito:

```
private void botoes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((Button)sender).Name); // imprime no Console o nome do botão clicado
}
```

Nesse caso o `sender` irá referenciar o componente que realizou o evento `Click`, caso você precise de alguma informação específica, você pode colocá-la na propriedade `Tag` de cada botão e posteriormente acessá-la assim `((Button)sender).Tag`